# How to display a textbox in place of text in a column in a table on button-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a small angular and php app. I want to display table and be able to edit it by displaying textbox in place of the old text on the click of a button. Can you please help me with the same. Thanks in advance

This is my controller

```
angular.module('directiveModule').controller('HomeController',['fetchServerData',function (fetchServerData) {

var ctrl = this;

ctrl.stateVal =  false;

ctrl.getTableData = function () {
    fetchServerData.getStudentsData()
        .then(
            function (response) {
                ctrl.tableData =response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        )
};

ctrl.init = function () {
    ctrl.getTableData();
};

ctrl.init();

ctrl.editPrice = function () {
    ctrl.stateVal = true;
};
```

}]);

This is the controller html

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Flowers</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="flower in home.tableData">
    <tr>
        <td>{{flower.name}}</td>
        <td click-to-edit price="flower.price" stateVal="home.stateVal"></td>
        <td><button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Price" ng-click="home.editPrice()"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using a directive to implement the replacement

```
angular.module('directiveModule').directive('clickToEdit',[function () {
    return{
        scope: {
            price : '=',
            stateVal : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/directiveTemplates/clickToEdit.html',
        restrict : 'EA',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.edit = scope.stateVal;
        }
    }
}]);
```

directive html

```
<div>
    <span ng-hide="edit">
        {{price}}
    </span>
    <div ng-show="edit">
        <input class="inputText" type="text"/>
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"  ng-click="save()"></div>
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="cancel()"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So this is my code, but the textbox does not appear on ng-click of the edit-pencil

Finally this is my json response

```
[{"name":"Lilies","price":200},{"name":"Carnations","price":200},{"name":"Roses","price":200},{"name":"Orchids","price":200},{"name":"Tulips","price":200}]
```

Please help me make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following observations need to be corrected in your code

1. The attribute name `stateVal` should be `state-val`
2. a) You should keep a watch on your `scope.stateVal` if you want to `scope.edit` to be effected when `click` happened.

   Or

   b) You can use `ng-hide="stateVal"` in `clickToEdit.html` instead of `ng-hide="edit"`.
3. The click event of the button should be called with `flower` variable inorder to isolate each `edit` of the row

   `<!-- HTML -->`

   `<button ng-click="home.editPrice(flower)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Price">Edit</span></button>`

   `/* Controller */`

   `ctrl.editPrice = function (flower) {
     flower.stateVal = true;
   };`

You can find the working code with above mentioned changes made in the following URL

[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ve6AAewoKAtuUHWczaDG?p=preview)

Or

https://plnkr.co/edit/ve6AAewoKAtuUHWczaDG?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You have error in :

```
<td click-to-edit price="flower.price" stateVal="home.stateVal"></td>
```

property must by lowercase letters with - (snake case):

```
 <td click-to-edit price="flower.price" state-val="home.stateVal"></td>
```

stateVal - > state-val